# How can I enable Brother printer's two-side printing functionality?

Tags: catalina, printing, driver

My Brother DCP-7055 Printer’s two-side printing functionality does not work (the “Two-Sided” option is greyed out) on macOS Catalina 10.15.4. I have not tested it on any other versions of macOS but it works as expected on Windows. I've installed the macOS driver from [the official Brother website](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp7055_all&os=10060), and the installed driver is Brother CUPS as it is [stated by Brother](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/143747/~/missing-the-option-to-print-on-both-sides-of-the-paper---windows-or-macintosh). Is there a workaround to enable this option of the device?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to look for Linux CUPS configurations if a printer seems not to be supported, but in this case even that doesn't seem to work (Linux driver is binary-only). Found [one page](https://www.colddiver.com/cups-and-airprint-with-brother-dcp-7030-dcp-7055-and-dcp-7065dn-on-freebsd-freenas-and-possibly-raspberry-pi/) where somebody made it work with CUPS but I'm not even sure it can be easily ported to macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page you linked, on the Printer driver download section, it specifically states:

> *Not all features are available for all products.

This is one of those features

Also on the [Supported OS page](https://support.brother.com/g/b/oslist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp7055_all), it likewise states:

> Please note that the available features may vary depending on the operating system.

It appears a Brother is using a generic(ish) CUPS PPD file meaning it’s a one-size-fits-all driver and two sided printing is simply not available.

It’s not a “popular” piece of advice, but your best bet is to get something with a bit more robustness in driver support like HP, Xerox, or Lexmark.  Brother has been really strong in the Windows space, not so much with Mac.

Comment: I appreciate your advice; actually this device is not new as I bought it almost ten year ago when I was a Mac user.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How were you sure about this issue being one of the unavailable features?

Comment: 1) Many years of experience, and 2) see nohillside's comment.  When you see a statement like that, it tells me that in all likely hood, the feature I want the most, won't be supported.  But, as for Brother, I inherited a number of printers at a school from the previous IT group and in attempting to get them to work, one of the features that wasn't covered in the generic PPD was double sided printing.  Brother printers are good provided you're a Windows dominant environment.